# What does the 'rc' in `.bashrc`, etc. mean?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, bashrc

Well, this is embarrassing. I feel like I just realised I don't know a loyal colleague's name after working with them for 10 years. "Hey, er... **cough!**, thanks for that great job you did on setting my aliases this morning..."

What do the letters `rc` signify in `.bashrc`, `.kshrc`, etc.?

If you know, please cite sources.

Even if you don't know, I'd also welcome unfounded assumptions, suggestions or alternatives if they're marked as such.

Comment: See also [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23482/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-nanorc-stand-for), [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for)

Comment: Some RC files from JS world - [What are `rc` files in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36212256/465053)

Comment: i thought resource config XD

Answer (score 283, accepted):

It stands for “[run commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_Commands)”.

This comes from [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT)’s [CTSS (Compatible Time-Sharing System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatible_Time-Sharing_System) and [Multics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics), where the idea that a command processing shell would be an ordinary program originated. CTSS had a program called RUNCOM (for “run commands”) and a script was called “a runcom” in the community where Unix originated, leading to the file extension `.rc` and generally to the `rc` abbreviation.

`rc` stuck as a name for any list of commands.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! Thanks! Given the quote from the link - "There was a facility that would execute a bunch of commands" - I'm glad they didn't call it .basheaboc

Answer (score 50):

It stands for "run commands."

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands):

> The term rc stands for the phrase "run commands". It is used for any file that contains startup information for a command. It is believed to have originated somewhere in 1965 from a runcom facility from the MIT Compatible Time-Sharing System (CTSS).
>
> From Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie: "There was a facility that would execute a bunch of commands stored in a file; it was called runcom for 'run commands', and the file began to be called 'a runcom'. rc in Unix is a fossil from that usage."
>
> Tom Van Vleck, a Multics engineer, has also reminisced about the extension rc: "The idea of having the command processing shell be an ordinary slave program came from the Multics design, and a predecessor program on CTSS by Louis Pouzin called RUNCOM, the source of the ".rc" suffix on some Unix configuration files."
>
> This is also the origin of the name of the Plan 9 from Bell Labs shell by Tom Duff, the rc shell. It is called 'rc' because the main job of a shell is to 'run commands'.
>
> While not historically precise, rc may also be expanded as "run control", because an rc file controls how a program runs. For instance, the editor Vim looks for and reads the contents of the .vimrc file to determine its initial configuration. In *The Art Of Unix Programming*, Eric S. Raymond consistently refers to rc files as "run-control" files.

Answer (score 10):

From [djeikyb](https://askubuntu.com/users/8515/djeikyb) on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23482/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-nanorc-stand-for/23486#23486):

> I've heard
>
> - run commands
> - resource control
> - run control
> - runtime configuration
>
> Personally, I'd go with run control, because ESR says so.
>
> [http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html)
>
> His footnote says:
>
> ```
> The ‘rc’ suffix goes back to Unix's grandparent, CTSS.
> It had a command-script feature called "runcom". Early
> Unixes used ‘rc’ for the name of the operating system's
> boot script, as a tribute to CTSS runcom.
> ```
>
> Wikipedia chooses "run commands" as the default long-form, but admits that context should determine word choice.
>
> ```
> While not historically precise, rc may also be pronou-
> nced as "run control", because an rc file controls how
> a program runs. For instance, the editor Vim looks for
> and reads the contents of the .vimrc file to determine
> its initial configuration. The most sensible pronunci-
> ation depends on the function of the file: to start
> something up, or to control how something starts up.
> ```
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_Commands

Comment: ESR seems to contradict himself. How is "runcom" an abbreviation of "run control"?